# Make the button on right and center on the card css

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a card in html which contains a button I wanted to display the button on the right and also center it in the card.I want to display the div with the class mydivbutton on the left and centered in the card

```
<div class="mycard">
    <div>
        <div class="">
            <a class="" href=""
                target="_blank">
                developpeur
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <span class="">
               soft
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mydivbutton">
        <button>My button </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear about what you already have and what you actually want.

You should try using flexbox. Be sure to specify a width and height to the class mycard, since this will be your flex. Then you can add justify-content:space-between; to clearify that you want the button separate from the rest of the text. Then add align-items: center; to specify that you want them to be vertically centered.

I did it like this as a reference

```
.mycard{
      width:300px;
      height: 100px;
      background: orange;
      
      display:flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

Comment: I use the flexbox but the button is not completely centered at the moment

Comment: @wilfrid can you share what styling are you aplying to your classes? is hard to guess what's going on without anything to look.

Answer (score 0):

The better implementation is using flexbox properties. Search for this and mainly for properties `justify-content` (which align your elements horizontally) and `align-items` (which align your elements vertically).

Comment: I use the flexbox but the button is not completely centered at the moment

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn about flexbox with CSS!
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And yours question was not clear :( I can't help you with accuracy. But you can send me a message at any time and i try to help u (sorry for my bad english, i'm brazilian)

Comment: I use the flexbox but the button is not completely centered at the moment

Comment: can you send me a screenshot of the code?